# Cauchy sequences of bounded linear operators is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ a normed space and $\{T_n\}\subseteq B(X, Y)$ such that $\{T_nx\}$ is Cauchy in $Y$ for every $x  \in X$. Show that norm $T_n$ is bounded.

My Question it is enough by uniform boundedness theorem to show norm every Cauchy sequence is bounded

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Every Cauchy sequence (x_n) is bounded,it s |x_n|< M for all n, then the norm of cauchy sequence is bounded too because ||x_n|| = |x_n| < M.

Then the sequence (|T_n(x)|) is bounded and satisfy the hypothesis of Banach-Steinhaus theorem and you can conclude that the sequence (|T_n|) is bounded, then |T_n| < M for any M.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).